# Find file in folder faster way

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am looking for the fastest and smallest code for powershell to look in a folder with subfolders to find a app.config file.

When a app.config file is found it shall call my function.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Small formatting fix for the code

Find file in folder fastes way

I am looking for the fastest and smallest code for powershell to look in a folder with subfolders to find a app.config file.

When a app.config file is found it shall call my function. Any suggestions?

My code below is just the transformation of an *app/web.config* so what I missing is a function that can search in a directory and get out a searchway to where an *app.config* file are.

So lets say `C:/temp` shall be searched. In here we have

```
 C:/temp/folder1/app.config 
 C:/temp/folder2/subfolder1/app.config
```

This will result in two findings. so my function below needs to be called twice.

```
param(
$XmlPath,
$XdtPath
)

function XmlDocTransform($xml, $xdt)
{    
    if (!$xml -or !(Test-Path -path $xml -PathType Leaf)) {
        throw "File not found. $xml";
    }

    if (!$xdt -or !(Test-Path -path $xdt -PathType Leaf)) {
        throw "File not found. $xdt";
    }

    $scriptPath = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value.InvocationName | split-path -parent
    Add-Type -LiteralPath "$scriptPath\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"

    $xmldoc = New-Object Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformableDocument;
    $xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
    $xmldoc.Load($xml);

    $transf = New-Object Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformation($xdt);

    if ($transf.Apply($xmldoc) -eq $false)
    {
        throw "Transformation failed."
    }

    $xmldoc.Save($xml);
}

XmlDocTransform $XmlPath $XdtPath
```

Comment: I understand the question, I am confused by your script. What does that do? Is that the function that should be called when the file is found? Please post your efforts around finding the file and share where it went wrong.

Comment: @Niels is it more clear now?

Comment: The question is still clear, but it seems to have nothing to do with the code above. That is just the function being called when an app.config file is found, right? Please paste the code that you wrote to find the files, and we can help you see where it fails.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -path C:/temp/ -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq 'app.config'} | % {XmlDocTransform -Xmlpath 'SomeXmlPath' -Xdtpath 'SomeXdtPath'}`?

Comment: @Niels I dont have any left since none of them worked. So I am still trying to find a way to get this to work. Thats why a wrote a question.

Comment: @Vivek. I will try it. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Recurse -Filter "app.config" | ForEach-Object { 
   $AppConfigPath = $_.FullName
   XmlDocTransform -XmlPath $AppConfigPath -XdtPath $yourotherpath
}
```

Comment: Get this error. 
Get-ChildItem : File not found. 
At E:\Appl\Jenkins\workspace\TestPowershell\Transform.ps1:34 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Appl\Jenkins\workspace\TestPowershell\ -Recurs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (File not found. :String) [Get-ChildItem], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : File not found. ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? If no files are found it should just return.

Comment: If I just add this: Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Recurse -Filter "app.config" then it gets a list of all app.config.....if I add the rest I get the error. I have even hardcoded the xmlpath and yourotherpath and still get the same error

Comment: So what happens if you comment out the XmlDocTransform command and add Write-Host $AppConfigPath in the loop. Then it works right? Now replace c:\temp with your real path, but put it in "" just to be sure. Does it still work?

Comment: Yes  then I get a list of app.config. So I guess it is the input to xmldoctranform that does the error.

Comment: It looks like the "File not found." is one of the errors  you throw yourself in the function. Try changing them to "XML file not found" or "XDT file not found" so you know which one goes wrong

Comment: You are right. It is in my code is goes wrong. It worked Before so I will check that out why

Comment: The error was XmlDocTransform -XmlPath $AppConfigPath -XdtPath $yourotherpath
should be XmlDocTransform  $AppConfigPath  $yourotherpath

Answer (score 1):

If you need it really fast, then I highly recommend to use robocopy for such task.
It is included in Windows since a while.

Here is a code-snippet to start with:

```
$list = New-Object 'Collections.ArrayList'
$files = &robocopy /l "c:\" /s \\localhost\c$\nul "app.config" /bytes /ns /njh /njs /np /nc /fp /ndl /xj
foreach($file in $files) {
    $data = $file.split("`t")
    $null = $list.add([tuple]::create([uint64]$data[3], $data[4]))
}
$list
```